# Javafx Image placeholder

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm creating an asset sharing application. The application loads tiles from data coming from my server. The users can download and upload assets from/to the server. An asset can have or not an image with it. The tiles use the asset image as background and or a default one if none is found on the server.

The asset itself is named with a hash, and if an image is provided, the image file is named the same, with a "png" extension, making it easy to find the images without DB queries or more work.

When the app loads, it gets the data from the server and loads the images on background.

I know there is a way to check if an image exists using the html return codes like

```
public static boolean urlExists(String url)
{
    try
    {
        HttpsURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        return (con.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

But that can take time, slowing down my loading process, as I load about 500 assets on launch.

So I thought, hey, just provide the url to the image constructor, anyway, if the url doesn't exist, we don't get an error, but an empty image....

```
tileBackground.setImage(getObj().getImageURL());
```

Problem, if that image is empty, I'd still like to display a placeholder...

I have tried to use Image.isError() / image.errorProperty() / image.exceptionProperty() but even if the url doesn't exist, these don't show it. So I thought, let^s make it this way:

```
Image image = new Image(MainApp.class.getResourceAsStream("view/img/default-tile-icon.png"));
ImageView tileBackground= new ImageView(image);
getObj()._image.progressProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue.intValue() == 1) {
            tileBackground.setImage(getObj().getImage());
        }
    });
```

So technically, set a default image for every tile, and when the object finishes loading the image, set it as the tile background... But non existing url image do load as well up to 100%...

Who would have a nicer idea to display a default image when the image doesn't display, without url checking that consumes a lot of time?

Comment: How does the code look like where you provide the data? You could send along the information if there is an image available together with the data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I could actually, but again, that's a server is_file() for every asset I want to send the client. It surely is faster than an html request though, that's true

Comment: But you could store whether or not a file is associated in your database, e.g. have an ImageFile table with simply the name of the image and the id of the asset. That way you avoid the check for files that might not exist (just using the data in the database instead). Then in the Java representation (entity) have an `Optional<String> imageFileName` or something similar. Then you just retrieve the file if the image file name exists, and show the placeholder otherwise.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answers. I thumbed up you both, as it is what I ended up doing, the data sent by the server tell the client whether or not there's an image available.